# Android: Calendar Event Callback

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need to trigger if a Calendar event scheduled for current time.The same way calendar app notify us for event. How can I add listener for this

Comment: Lets say I have 10 meetings today, so should I have to schedule all those events

Answer (score 1):

That is the job for the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). There you can define when you want to be invoked to trigger your notification. If you want to use a more convenience library try [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) from evernote they handle the differences of the different platforms, since there where some chances over the time.

Basically for all of those three implementations you plan when your reciever should be invoked and then you show your notification. Keep in mind that the AlarmManager won't manage your pending notifications after a reboot, while the JobScheduler has this option, but requires api level 21.

It seems that you are more interested to read the events out of the calendar of your device. You can read out the calendar with the [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html). The documentation should be fine enough to find out the details yourself.

Comment: Actually I am looking for  listener for Calendar events, take an example in my calendar I have meeting between 2 to 4 pm. So how app receive this event at 2 pm.

Comment: That is a totally different story. You need to check the calendar provider and read that events you are interested in.